# Are there additional rewards for finishing missions with 3 gold stars?

Tags: mission-control-nanomech

In Mission Control: Nanomech it appears that as long as you finish a mission without yourself or Titan falling then you are able to continue to the next mission, and so far every completed mission has awarded me 6 tech points to upgrade myself plus a static bonus to me or my robots, no matter how good or bad my performance was in the mission.

However I am yet to attain 3 gold stars in a mission, and would like to know if there is any additional reward for getting all 3 gold stars, or whether the rewards truly are static regardless of your performance in the mission?